# PostgreSQL query causing cpu to spike to 100%. Given 90k records, is a cost of 7000 ok?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, delayed-job, postgresql-9.1

I'm working to understand how cost and actual time should be used to optimize queries. My app is rails 3 with a PostgreSQL 9.1 db. My query is used by Delayed_job:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT  "delayed_jobs".*
FROM "delayed_jobs"
WHERE ((run_at <= '2011-05-23 15:16:43.180810' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2011-01-25 11:05:28.077144') OR locked_by = 'host:foo pid:2') AND failed_at IS NULL AND queue = 'authentication_emails')
ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 5
```

Or:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT  "delayed_jobs".*
FROM "delayed_jobs"
WHERE ((run_at <= '2011-05-23 15:16:43.180810' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2011-01-25 11:05:28.077144') OR locked_by = 'host:foo pid:2') AND failed_at IS NULL )
ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 5
```

For the first query, the output equals:

```
Limit  (cost=7097.57..7097.57 rows=1 width=1008) (actual time=35.657..35.657 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=7097.57..7097.57 rows=1 width=1008) (actual time=35.655..35.655 rows=0 loops=1)
        Sort Key: priority, run_at
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
        ->  Seq Scan on delayed_jobs  (cost=0.00..7097.56 rows=1 width=1008) (actual time=35.648..35.648 rows=0 loops=1)
              Filter: ((failed_at IS NULL) AND ((queue)::text = 'authentication_emails'::text) AND (((run_at <= '2011-05-23 15:16:43.18081'::timestamp without time zone) AND ((locked_at IS NULL) OR (locked_at < '2011-01-25 11:05:28.077144'::timestamp without time zone))) OR (locked_by = 'host:foo pid:2'::text)))
Total runtime: 35.695 ms
```

The table currently has 90k records and can range from 0-200k. We're noticing this query is causing the CPU to spike and cause bottlenecks. What can be learned from the explain info above. Where should indexes be added if any? Thanks

**DB Schema.. Table has 0 indexes.**

```
  create_table "delayed_jobs", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "priority",   :default => 0
    t.integer  "attempts",   :default => 0
    t.text     "handler"
    t.text     "last_error"
    t.datetime "run_at"
    t.datetime "locked_at"
    t.datetime "failed_at"
    t.text     "locked_by"
    t.datetime "created_at",                :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                :null => false
    t.string   "queue"
  end
```

Comment: About how many records satisfy the `where` clause?  Does the table fit into memory?

Comment: re: satisfy it's a wide range, anywhere from 0 to all of them. How do I know if the table fits into memory?

Comment: . . How wide are the rows?  This type of query should not be taking very much time -- if more than a handful of seconds then something seems amiss with the hardware or configuration.

Comment: 12 fields it's delayed_job. Will update q w schema.

Comment: Details updated in the q. Does that help?

Comment: The explain says that the query runs in 35 milliseconds and that the `delayed_jobs` table contains only 1 row. This is either not the production database, or you don't have current statistics. `ANALYZE` the table and try again?

Comment: Exactly. Also the database over-estimates the required time: 7 seconds instead of 35 ms. Probably the statistics are off or absent, and estimated_cache_size is set too low, and all the disk contents happily sit in buffers.

Comment: Correct, this is locally, but using the prod db data from when we had performance issues. It's no longer an issue on prod so it's hard to test.

Comment: That's why sort and limit cost is 0.01

Comment: @wildplasser cost != time.

Comment: That is correct. But it is still way off. I'd start by removing the sort+limit. But probably the tuning is per default, too (IIRC 9.1 has better defaults). BTW: I don't like the scenario "just add some indexes". The OP will have to design the whole schema, not just some object storage. Does this table have a PK? On second thought: all the time seems to be spent scanning memory.

Comment: that seems like a lot of delayed_job records, not sure if it is meant to deal with that kind of load - might be time to upgrade to a queueing system? Guessing you have multiple delayed_job processes running as well and they are all probably trying to query for their next work batch at the same time making the issue even worse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Analysis**

If you will go [this section of the PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/using-explain.html), you will learn how planner is using statistics to estimate costs. This is very usable information!

If you say, that table has round 90k records (and using [default costs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-SEQ-PAGE-COST)), then cost for rows' processing will be:

```
90000 * (cpu_tuple_cost + cpu_operator_cost) = 90000 * 0.0125 = 1125
```

We can now approximate how many pages your table occupies:

```
(7097.56-1125)/seq_page_cost = 5972.56
```

Which makes it roughly 46Mb (with default 8k page size). Thus I assume your table fits into the [shared_buffers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-SHARED-BUFFERS), even default ones.

Looking at the average row width I also assume, that table is [mostly stored as `MAIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/storage-toast.html).

Next, you're using fields of type `text` and `string` as predicates. Not sure how they map to the PostgreSQL internal types, but I would assume it is `text`. This type is compressable by default, therefore PostgreSQL has to perform de-compression for each row to check predicates. I'm not sure after which threshold compression kicks off, take a look at [this message](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/23724.1093538844@sss.pgh.pa.us) (and the whole thread).

**Conclusion**

1. You haven't shown us real `EXPLAIN (analyze)` output, as I also don't think that 35ms query can cause bottlenecks, except...
2. You haven't mentioned how many sessions are using your database at the bottleneck moments, and also it is not clear how frequently this query is run. I assume that it is very popular one.
3. Your table seems to fit into the memory, therefore all operations *will be* CPU-bound in any case.
4. Values used in the predicates are compressable and seems to be compressed.

Therefore I'd said that bottleneck comes from the peak amount of queries run in parallel on the data, that requires extra CPU cycles for de-compression.

**What to do?**

1. Normalise your table. It feels that “queue” column is of very low selectivity. Consider creating [external type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtype.html) (like `ENUM`) for it, or organize a dictionary table with a proper Foreign Key. I'm also not sure bout `locked_by` column, can it be normalised?
2. Create indexes on `run_at` and `locked_at` columns.
3. Index `ON priority, run_at` columns will benefit your sorts, but I doubt it will help in this case. I assume that `priority` column is of low selectivity, therefore planner will prefer to use `Bitmap And` over `Index Scans` on `run_at` and `locked_at` columns.

I hope I am not terribly wrong here :) Comments/corrections are welcome!

P.S. Let me know how it goes for you.

Answer (score 0):

`Where should indexes be added?`

As phrased, the particular SQL query has no columns that would make excellent candidates for an index: your use of the < operator on a date-time column would return (possibly) a large resultset, if you have a lot of historic data. The larger the resultset returned from the index when satisfying the condition, the less efficiency (less power to reduce) that index has in the context of the given query. Further, in some databases NULLs don't get indexed, so any test for NULL requires a table-scan. Not sure about PostgreSQL 9.1 in respect to NULL values in an index.